# Bandwidth of a pulse code modulation system

Tags: digital-communications, bandwidth, bit-rate

Original test question:

> 24 telephone channels, each bandlimited to 3.4kHz are to be time division multiplexed by using pulse code modulation. Calculate the bandwidth of pulse code modulation system for 128 quantization levels and 8kHz sampling frequency?

The solution for this question is given as follows:

> bandwidth = (no. of channels) * (sampling frequency) * (bit depth)
>
> bit depth = 7 and  sampling frequency = 8kHz
>
> So, bandwidth = 24 * 8k * 7 = 1.34MHz

My doubt here is that, as far as I know, the product of sampling frequency and bit depth gives bit rate; but here, it is stated that it gives bandwidth.

Are bandwidth and bit rate the same for digital signals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right; while "colloquially" bandwidth sometimes refers to a data rate (e.g. in "I have a DSL line with a bandwidth of 100 Mb/s" is technically wrong, but people say things like that), as an answer in a technical lecture, bandwidth has to be considered as amount of frequency space occupied by a signal.

I think the answer is half right, but the question is wrong: PCM is a *digital* thing; if you wanted to talk about bandwidth, you'd need to specify how the PCM samples (which are just values, like "15" or "-3", no physical meaning in itself) are brought to the analog medium "telephone trunking cable" (which carries *voltages* or *currents* or maybe field densities or such analog things). So, it makes no sense to talk about bandwidth of a digital signal by itself; only data rate makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Marcus's answer a bit, sometimes an explicit distinction is made between "digital bandwidth" in units of bits/second and "analog bandwidth" in units of Hertz. But sometimes that distinction is implicit in the context, which is probaby what's happening here. The **analog** bandwidth of the individual voice channels is described as being 3.4 kHz, while the question is asking about the **digital** bandwidth of the resulting multiplexed signal, in megabits per second — although they use the term "MHz" instead.

And indeed, for binary channels that have only two states, the two concepts are actually closely related. While it can be argued that an alternating stream of ones and zeros conveys two bits per cycle, implying that the analog bandwidth might be half of the digital bandwidth, such a signal actually carries zero information — it is completely predictable. However, if you look at the frequency content of a "more random" stream of data, you'll find that it "fattens out" until much of the signal energy fills an analog bandwidth that is in fact approximately numerically equal to the digital bandwidth. If you artificially constrain the analog bandwidth to a value less than that, you'll find that it becomes quite difficult to reliably recover the digital data.

I worked in telecom for several years, building equipment (T1 terminal multiplexers) very similar to what your question is describing. At one point, I ran a series of numerical simulations that illustrated the bandwidth relationship quite nicely.

Comment: can you explain how the alternating stream of ones and zeroes have digital bandwidth twice of that of the analog bandwidth and why it doesn't carry any information and also why making it more unpredictable (random) makes the digital bandwidth approximately the same as the analog bandwidth ?

Comment: Alternating ones and zeros can be filtered down to a single sine wave whose frequency is equal to 1/2 the bit rate. You can think of this as removing all but the first component in the Fourier transform of the square wave. The original data waveform is easily recovered by putting the sine wave through an analog comparator with its threshold at zero volts. Like I said, this signal contains zero information because it is 100% predictable.

Comment: On the other hand, the Fourier transform a random binary signal (unpredictable) is a series of broad "humps" in the frequency domain. Each hump spreads over a bandwidth that is basically equal to twice the bit rate. If you use a low-pass filter to isolate one of those humps, you can still use the comparator to recover the digital waveform. This continues to work well if you reduce the bandwidth to be equal to the bit rate -- you're still capturing about 2/3 of the signal energy, and the time-waveform continues to look relatively clean.

Comment: But if you go much below that, intersymbol interference starts to produce bit errors at the output of the comparator. The time-domain waveform becomes obviously distorted.

Comment: so, according to my understanding, If we consider a random binary signal, then consider it's Fourier transform, it'll result in a series of humps. And, the BW of each hump i.e. the difference between upper and lower 3dB frequencies gives the bandwidth of each character. These humps can be separated using an LPF with BW of twice the bit rate, the signal can be recovered without overlapping of symbols and the BW of LPF can be lowered until it's BW is equal to the bit rate. If it's lowered even more than the bit rate, the symbols will overlap. Is it right?

Comment: And also, how is the Fourier transform of a stream of binary data calculated?